Dockerized spring gateway application giving 431 request headers too large
Need help in one of the issue.While dockerizing the microservices and hitting postman via api gateway port exposed in docker -compose file, getting error 431 Request Header too large while before dockerizing locally it was working fine.Any resolution in this regard shall be helpful
I tried changing the server.max.http-header-size in Api gateway application and in other microservices to 16843 and inspected the request size in postman headers it is less than 16843

Which Spring Boot version are you using? Since v3.0 the property has changed, now it's server.max-http-request-header-size. Maybe adding the docker layer make the header to be enriched with some informations, and that are the ones that make the size break the limit?
